# How to convert string to char in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val StringCharacter = "A"
    val CharCharacter = StringCharacter.toChar()
    println(CharCharacter)
}
```

I am unable to convert string A to char.
I know that StringCharacter = 'A' makes it char but I need the conversion.

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work in your code snippet?

Comment: Unresolved reference: toChar()

Comment: `val c = StringCharacter[0]` you will get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is String is empty

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A [`CharSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char-sequence/index.html) (e.g. [`String`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/index.html)) can be empty, have a single character, or have more than one character.

If you want a function that "returns the single character, or throws an exception if the char sequence is empty or has more than one character" then you want [`single`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/single.html):

```
val string = "A"
val char = string.single()
println(char)
```

And if you want to call `single` by a different name you can create your own [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) to do so:

```
fun CharSequence.toChar() = single()
```

Usage:

```
val string = "A"
val char = string.toChar()
println(char)
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot convert a `String` to a `Char`, because a `String` is an array of `Chars`. Instead, select a `Char` from the `String`:

```
val string = "A"
val character = string.get(0) // Or string[0]
println(character)
```

Comment: `get(0)` and `[0]` is the same in kotlin, so you can get the first character with `string[0]` which is more idiomatic

Answer (score 5):

A String cannot be converted to a Char because String is an array of chars. You can convert a String to an Char array or you can get a character from that String.

Example:

```
val a = "Hello"
val ch1 = a.toCharArray()[0]   // output: H 
val ch2 = a[0]    // output: H
```